# Login Button Function

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi3

I am experimenting with `tkinter` in python.

At the moment I have created a script which creates a login window which has no function what so ever. I have tried playing around with the `def callback():` and `command=callback`. So I tried making it so that when you press the "Login" button, you can do something (e.g. show loading... and clear text boxes.)

Here is the code:

```py
import tkinter

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("Login")
window.geometry("250x150")
window.configure(background="#FFFFFF")

label = tkinter.Label(window, text="Please Login to continue:", bg="#FFFFFF", font=("PibotoLt", 16))
label.pack()
label = tkinter.Label(window, text="username:", bg="#FFFFFF")
label.pack()
entry = tkinter.Entry(window)
entry.pack()
label = tkinter.Label(window, text="password:", bg="#FFFFFF")
label.pack()
entry = tkinter.Entry(window)
entry.pack()

def callback():
    button = tkinter.Button(window, text="Login", fg="#FFFFFF", bg="#000000")
    button.pack()
    label = tkinter.Label(window, text="Loading...", bg="#FFFFFF", command=callback)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: So the question is - how to make a button?Also, please format the code with the `code markdown`

Comment: Move this `.Label(..., command=callback` to the `.Button(..., command=callback` and **add** a `    print('Hello World)'` to your `def callback():`.

Comment: I tried to clarify the code but I'm not 100% I got the indentation right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three issues:

1. The callback function needs to be assigned to the command option on the Button widget.
2. The two entry widgets need different variable names for access in the callback
3. The callback function needs a body of code that does something.

The code should be

```
import tkinter

window = tkinter.Tk()

window.title("Login")
window.geometry("250x150")
window.configure(background="#FFFFFF")

label = tkinter.Label(window, text="Please Login to continue:", bg="#FFFFFF", font=("PibotoLt", 16))
label.pack()
label = tkinter.Label(window, text="username:", bg="#FFFFFF")
label.pack()
entry0 = tkinter.Entry(window) # Renamed entry0 to find in callback
entry0.pack()
label = tkinter.Label(window, text="password:", bg="#FFFFFF")
label.pack()
entry1 = tkinter.Entry(window) # Renamed entry1 to differentiate from entry0
entry1.pack()

def callback():
    """ Callback to process a button click. This will be called whenever the button is clicked.
        As a simple example it simply prints username and password.
    """
    print("Username: ", entry0.get(), "    Password: ", entry1.get())

button = tkinter.Button(window, text="Login", fg="#FFFFFF", bg="#000000", command=callback)
button.pack()

window.mainloop()
```